# Oauth2 External Browser Request - App Launches, Credentials received, Browser Not Updated

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I am using an external browser request to authenticate myself with the SoundCloudAPI in `OSX`. 
My app launches, and has a button that opens an external browser window to authenticate against SoundCloud. When I click "connect" in the new window, I get a "External Protocol Request" that is consistent with my custom launch URI scheme. Clicking this puts focus back on the already opened app, and it gets the correct credentials.

The trouble is, the browser window never changes - it simply says that it's connecting forever. There is no "connection confirmed" alert coming from SoundCloud. I know been authenticated because I can make the correct calls to the API to get things such as my username.

Why isn't the browser confirming the connection or dismissing?

The same thing happens if I load the authentication in an internal `WebView` in the app.

---

Perhaps the issue is that the SoundCloud Connect webpage that pops up in the browser needs to be told that the app has connected? Is this a correct line of thinking? How would I achieve that?

---

So, I added some code that listens for a change in `SCSoundCloudAccountDidChangeNotification` and then closes the window:

```
- (void)notificationReceived:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
{
    NSLog(@"%@", aNotification.name);
    SCAccount *account = [SCSoundCloud account];
    NSLog(@"%@", account.description);

    if ([SCSoundCloud account] && [aNotification.name isEqualToString:SCSoundCloudAccountDidChangeNotification]) {
        [_window close];

    }
}
```

To me, this seems pretty dirty - is this how other apps do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch if the request is completed or not by using

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

or

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource
```

Please check these two methods and one of them should be working when the request is completed. Then, you can take necessary actions like refreshing the webview, etc...

Comment: I changed my code to use a webview, and used the first method like so:
`- (void) webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    NSString *currentURL = [[[[frame dataSource] request]URL]absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"Our WebView just loaded: %@", currentURL);
    if ([currentURL hasPrefix:@"SCMOSX://connect"]) {
        NSLog(@"We're here!");
    }
}

NSLog prints: `Our WebView just loaded: https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=MYCLIENTID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=SCMOSX%3A%2F%2Fconnect&display=popup` but I never get the second `"We're here"`